# The performance of LoadStartingWith in RavenDb

Tags: ravendb

I have a theoretic concern about `LoadStartingWith` performance. Let's take an example from the [documentation](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.5/csharp/client-api/basic-operations/loading-editing-existing-document):

```
BlogPost[] prefixedResultsWithMatch = session.Advanced
    .LoadStartingWith<BlogPost>("blogposts/1", "*/Author/*t");
```

So we do not have an index. This "query" goes directly to the store. How can it execute it efficiently (without fullscan)? Is there any internal index for ids at the RavenDb or storage (esent, Voron) level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way it works, we have the prefix, and an index of the id.
So we can scan only the documents matching the prefix you gave.
But then we have to match each an every one of them to the filter you have.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Raven always keeps the document ids indexed.

If you execute a query on a type without any query parameters, Raven doesn't have to create an auto index as the ids that point to the actual documents are already known by Raven.

So that's kind of the same thing as that "load query" that doesn't use an index.